# How to get alert when the system goes down?

Tags: monitoring

We would like to monitor few servers,like if the server goes down i 
should get a pop-up instantly without fail. I know it is possible, 
but i have no idea on how to setup it. It will be so kind if someone helps
me to setup it. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ping. Although ping failure doesn't necessarily mean that your system is down, it can also happen if the network is down but I believe for most intents and purposes these are same thing. You can use following script

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="cyberciti.biz theos.in router"

COUNT=4

for myHost in $HOSTS
do
  count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
    # 100% failed 
    echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
  fi
done
```

This is from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/simple-linux-and-unix-system-monitoring-with-ping-command-and-scripts.html). You can also setup a cron job for this or any similar script to ping all your servers after a regular interval.

Answer (score 2):

[Nagstamon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nagstamon) [image: Install nagstamon] might be useful.

From their [website](http://nagstamon.ifw-dresden.de/):

Nagstamon is a Nagios status monitor for the desktop. It connects to multiple Nagios, Icinga, Opsview, Centreon, Op5 Monitor/Ninja and Check_MK Multisite monitoring servers and resides in systray or as a floating statusbar at the desktop showing a brief summary of critical, warning, unknown, unreachable and down hosts and services and pops up a detailed status overview when moving the mouse pointer over it. Connecting to displayed hosts and services is easily established by context menu via SSH, RDP and VNC. Users can be notified by sound. Hosts and services can be filtered by category and regular expressions.

[image: im1]

<sub>Not used it myself and I do not see the ability for mail notification (what I'd favor)</sub>